# SSRS - First row border in tablix is not bolded

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to make a solid bold upper border for each row in tablix so that it looks like a bold line between each row. However, the first line in tablix doesn't have the same style as other rows - instead of having a bold upper border, the line has normal style (ignore the red bolded lines):

[image]

As you can see, each row is numbered (1. , 2. , 3. , etc...) and there is a straight line above each row. The problem is visible in first row - the upper line is not bolded like other lines.

Here are the settings for each row's border:

[image]

Is there an option I'm supposed to set? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just tried it and I did not find any issue both on table and on Matrix. Left hand side has Table and right hand side has Matrix

[image]